# Is it possible to create a notch in a shadowed box with pure css?

Tags: css

I'm currently struggling with a layout where I'm asking myself if this is possible with pure css or if I have to use images.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image: notch in a box]

So the `<body>` is the yellow area whereas the white box is the `<header>` where an area is sort of cut off. The shadow and the rounded corners are the tricky stuff here.

[I just fiddled around a bit](http://jsfiddle.net/945MZ/6/).

Answer (score 1):

Add a div inside the header and give position:absolute. Style the dive according to your mock. (I couldn't get bottom curves :( )

```
header {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 0 8px;
    height: 100px;
    position:relative
}
.curve{
    background: #fcf5e5;
     border-radius:14px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 4px 8px -5px #333;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 4px 8px -5px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 4px 8px -5px #333;
    height:60px;
    width:250px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0; right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    bottom:-9px
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/945MZ/4/)**

Comment: Thanks, this is already one step closer - but the tricky things really are the rounded borders, which are necessary here :-(

Comment: I updated my fiddle, I just got a little closer, but it's still not perfect.